# Trying to implement Django authentication through django-rest-framework-jwt. Why do I get "ValueError: Empty module name"?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have an existing, working Django application that implements numerous Django-REST-framework APIs.
Now I'm trying to add user authentication APIs as described in [**Django-rest-framework-JWT**](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt). But it is not working.

First, I installed Django-rest-framework-JWT using `pip`. No problem.

Then I added the following block to my `REST_FRAMEWORK` variable in my `settings.py`:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
),
```

Finally, I added the following line to the `urls.py` in my app's directory (IE: not the global `urls.py`):

```
url(r'^api-token-auth/', 'rest_framework_jwt.views.obtain_jwt_token'),
```

When I then started my server, I got the following ugly error: `ValueError: Empty module name`. Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 75, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 23, in <module>
    mod = import_module(app)
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/authority/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from authority.sites import site, get_check, get_choices_for, register, unregister
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/authority/sites.py", line 7, in <module>
    from authority.permissions import BasePermission
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/authority/permissions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from authority.models import Permission
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/authority/models.py", line 10, in <module>
    from authority.utils import User
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/authority/utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    User = get_user_class()
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/authority/utils.py", line 6, in get_user_class
    return auth.get_user_model()
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 127, in get_user_model
    user_model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 271, in get_model
    self._populate()
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/models.py", line 15, in <module>
    User = get_user_model()
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 127, in get_user_model
    user_model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 271, in get_model
    self._populate()
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 97, in load_app
    app_module = import_module(app_name)
  File "/opt/virtualEnvs/myApp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ValueError: Empty module name
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using? It seems like the minimum supported version is `1.4`

Comment: Django Version = 1.6.5

Comment: Inside your virtualenv can you provide the info from `pip list`?

Comment: Here is the output of `pip list`: https://gist.github.com/syedsaqibali/36d501464bdd3ae458bb

Comment: So first, this ValueError typically comes from a typo in `settings.py` but this stack trace is terminating nearest to the database model code in Django. Try perhaps doing `./manage.py syncdb` and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Sigmavirus24, hmm. I think you solved the problem. There must have been a typo in `settings.py`. Because when I re-inserted the JWT stuff (I had removed it), it now works.

Comment: Well there's no way to provide an answer for this that *should* be accepted because I can't really provide you an answer. Sorry that your 50 reputation points will go to waste. :/

Comment: Meh, it happens. Not gonna loose sleep over it :) Thanks Sigma.

Comment: Here is my follow-up question that I will probably be issuing a bounty for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878583/how-to-login-users-with-email-and-log-them-out-with-django-rest-framework-json-w